# Magento $product->save() runs for ever ... hours now

Tags: performance, magento, save, product

I have these instructions :

```
 $prd = $modelp->loadByAttribute('sku', $psku);
 $prd->setStatus((int)$status);
 $prd->save();
```

I checked and indeed the product had saved and status changed, however the last instruction runs for hours. Maybe you think instructions after, no I am sure (I can check that in a written list) and if I skip these instructions the program finish quickly. I read all products and only one product have to be changed, there it hangs.

So I have to terminate this program and to ask to my customer to change such product (sometimes one) manually, because of this problem ...

What can be the reason (version 1.5) ?

I got this error finally:

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1205 Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction

I am busy alone on the system, what can be the reason ?

This has to do probably with the re-index of prices UPDATE ON SAVE ... that gives a lock sometimes ..

Comment: Maybe my customer was running a datasheet with updates, I shall ask later (sleeping now) ...

Comment: This was not the case, it has to do with the re-index of prices UPDATE ON SAVE ..